# Foo.bar - PowerHungry: multiply every number in a list that are larger than 0 and return it as absolute value

Tags: python, arrays

I m trying to solve an algorithm challenge. Which requires multiplying every element in a list with each other and returning the absolute value as a string. A quote from the question is;

> So for example, if an array contained panels with power output levels
> of [2, -3, 1, 0, -5], then the maximum product would be found by
> taking the subset: xs[0] = 2, xs[1] = -3, xs[4] = -5, giving the
> product 2*(-3)*(-5) = 30.  So solution([2,-3,1,0,-5]) will be "30".

So here is my code;

```
def solution(xs):
    # Your code here
    import numpy as np

    empty = []

    for i in xs:
        if i == 0:
            continue
        else:
            empty.append(i)
        
    result = np.prod(empty)

    return str(abs(result))

print(solution([2, -1, 2, 2, 0]))
```

output: 8

Even though I receive the expected answer I pass only one test out of 5

Comment: Your code does what is required it seems

Comment: Nevertheless, it still fails the tests